# MATLAB - Approximating the integral with hemisphere domain with sample data

Tags: matlab, shader, bsxfun

The integral part of the [rendering equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendering_equation) performs an integral over a hemisphere range (with respect to solid angle).
I can generate samples that carry the value of corresponding integrand with this code:

```
n = 10;
rho_s = 0.5;
rho_d = 0.5;

light_phi = degtorad(30);
light_theta = degtorad(60);
[lx ly lz] = sph2cart(light_phi, light_theta, 1);

refDir = cat(3, -lx, -ly, lz);
normal = cat(3, 0, 0, 1);

[sample_phi sample_theta] = meshgrid(0:12:360, 0:3:90);
[sample_x sample_y sample_z] = sph2cart(degtorad(sample_phi), degtorad(sample_theta), 1);
viewDir = cat(3, sample_x, sample_y, sample_z);

dotRL = sum(bsxfun(@times, viewDir, refDir), 3);
dotRL = max(dotRL, 0);

brdf_s = rho_s*(n+2)*(dotRL.^n)/(2*pi);
brdf_d = rho_d/pi;
brdf = brdf_s + brdf_d;

x = sample_x.*brdf; y = sample_y.*brdf; z = sample_z.*brdf;
mesh(x, y, z);
line([0 lx],[0 ly],[0 lz]);

axis equal; axis vis3d;
xlim([-1 1]); ylim([-1 1]); zlim([0 1]);
```

The question I face now is how to do the integral or approximation with these samples?

Comment: Have you tried Matlab's [`integral`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html) function?

Comment: If the samples are distributed uniformly, just sum them up multiplying on some elementary area. If not, you can use the interpolation to get uniform distribution. For this purpose, one  usually uses TriScatteredInterp() or interp2() matlab functions. I will give you more details if this comment fits your question

Comment: I think i should make my question more clear:
(1) The integral is performed with respect to solid angle over a hemisphere, does MATLAB support any function that can do solid angle integral ?
(2) What i want to do is calculating the equation 2 in this [link](http://www.oceanopticsbook.info/view/radiative_transfer_theory/level_2/the_lambertian_brdf) and now i just have uniform sampled data on hemisphere that carry BRDF term, so how to calculate the integral with these sample data ?

Comment: It looks like the equations are just formulated as several surface integrals (`0` to `2*pi` domain -or some hemispherical domain, the text isn't very clear) - you can substitute in `dOmega = sin(Theta)*dTheta*dPhi`. I think `integral2` should work. Do you have a simple case that you can run (ideally one where you know the answer or at least the shape of the answer) to test if you've implemented everything right and the results are what you expect?

Comment: Ok, now it works after a substitution with omega and using the integral2, thanks for all the suggestions you provided.

Comment: @horchler I looks like you could turn your comment into an answer.